# Remove suffix of a delimited multiline string

Tags: bash, shell, sed, posix, sh

While trying to script safely handling filenames while handling newlines safely, I came across a difficult test case.

Given the input

```
a.b.c
.d.staging
```

where this input represents a single filename, I want to strip the `.staging` suffix. I would normally use something akin to `| rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev` for this, but this fails:

```
echo -ne "a.b.c\\n.d.staging" | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev
```

yields

```
a.b
.d
```

In addition to having lost the `c` component in addition to the `staging` suffix, there's also a lone newline at the end there Markdown is hiding.

The best solution I've come up with so far is to use `sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`, which appears to work:

```
echo -ne "a.b.c\\n.d.staging" | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'
```

yields

```
a.b.c
.d
```

which is the correct output.

This seems an inelegant solution, as it's hammering `sed` into handling newlines, which is something `sed` isn't great at doing.

Is there a more elegant solution? Ideally a POSIX-compatible one.

Comment: You need to learn about [parameter expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) (there's more sweet stuff in Bash's [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)). Look at chepner's and anubhava's examples and learn from the reference!

Comment: I wasn't sure if parameter expansions were POSIX-compatible. [Per chepner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730821/remove-suffix-of-a-delimited-multiline-string#comment66759522_39730879), they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the name in a variable, the newline is not an issue.

```
$ fname=$'a.b.c\n.d.staging'
$ echo "$fname"
a.b.c
.d.staging
$ echo "${fname%.*}"
a.b.c
.d
$
```

Comment: I saw `${string%word}` in `bash(1)`, but wasn't sure if that's a Bashism or is supported in POSIX mode. Is that a portable construct?

Comment: [It's portable.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Answer (score 2):

Using BASH you can do:

```
$> s=$'a.b.c\n.d.staging'

$> echo "$s"
a.b.c
.d.staging

$> echo "${s%.staging}"
a.b.c
.d
```

Without BASH support you can use `awk` like this using null `RS`:

```
printf "%b" 'a.b.c\n.d.staging' | awk -v RS= '{sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "")} 1'

a.b.c
.d
```

Comment: The parameter expansion `${var%stuff}` is valid POSIX. No need to use an external tool!

Comment: Oh that `print` is just a portable replacement for `echo -ne "a.b.c\\n.d.staging"`

Comment: Needs `-v ORS= ` to avoid a spurious newline added to the output, from my tests.